# Show that: $\chi(G) + \chi(\overline{G}) \leq |V| + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Show that: $\chi(G) + \chi(\overline{G}) \leq |V| + 1$

I have problem with starting with this task. I have already done similar ones like for example $\chi(G) * \chi(\overline{G}) \geq |V|$, but I can't really find the proper way of thinking to solve the task mentioned at the beginning.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried induction on the number of vertices?

Comment: Not yet. Don't really know how to use it in this case as I haven't seen usage of induction in tasks of this type, but I will try to check if I will be to figure out something with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** This can be proved by induction on $n(G)$, the number of vertices.

Choose any vertex $v$ of $G$. By the inductive hypothesis we have:
$$\chi(G-v)+\chi(\overline{G-v})\le n(G-v)+1=n(G)\tag1$$
and we also have
$$\chi(G)\le\chi(G-v)+1\tag2$$
and
$$\chi(\overline G)\le\chi(\overline{G-v})+1\tag3$$
whence
$$\chi(G)+\chi(\overline G)\le n(G)+2.\tag4$$
All we have to do now is show that equality can't hold in $(4)$. Well, for equality to hold in $(4)$, we must have equality in $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$. But then . . .

**Further hint:**

> Equality in $(2)$ implies $\deg_G(v)\ge\chi(G-v)$

Comment: Emm... A lot of time has passed since I asked that question, but was trying to focus on other classes.

So if we would like to have equality in (2) then $deg(v) = \Delta(G)$ or am I wrong? In that case it would not be possible to have equality in (3), right?

Comment: As I said in my **Further hint**, equality in $(2)$ implies $\deg_G(v)\ge\chi(G-v)$. If all the inequalities are equalities, then we have $$n(G)-1=\deg_G(v)+\deg_{\overline G}(v)\ge\chi(G-v)+\chi(\overline{G-v})=n(G),$$ i.e., $n(G)-1\ge n(G)$, a contradiction.